# looking for an ip address on a word document using wildcards

Tags: regex, ms-word

I'm looking for an ip address on a word document using wildcards, I tried using:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9];
```

which returns "too complex". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget [quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You should write something like `^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$`. It will find all valid IP V4 adresses.

Comment: doesn't work for me :( may be word version plays a role, whatever I used (<[0-9]@>.<[0-9]@>.<[0-9]@>.<[0-9]@>), and it's just sufficient :)

Comment: What exactly __doesn't work__ ? I'm using this regex tester (sorry, French website) http://www.annuaire-info.com/outil-referencement/expression-reguliere/ , I put the regex in "Modèle" and some IP adresses in "Chaîne1", "Chaîne2" etc, then click on "Evaluer l'expression régulière" And the results are expected results (as far as I test)...

Comment: @AlexB: it won't work with Word's internal regular expression syntax because Word has its own, very old, dialect.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the advanced search in MS Word with wildcards turned on. This worked best for me:

```
[0-9]{1;3}\.[0-9]{1;3}\.[0-9]{1;3}\.[0-9]{1;3}
```